# STM32 aux LED stays on in low voltage

Tags: stm32

I am trying to turn an auxiliary LED on PG13, on and off, the problem is when I put the registers on low voltage, the led stays on, it just gets dimmer.

This is my code:

```
#include "stm32f429xx.h"

int main(void)
{
     
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= 0x40;                                       
    
    GPIOG->MODER |= 0b00010100000000000000000000000000;                             
    
    while(1)
    {
        GPIOG->BSRR = 0b0010000000000000;                               
        GPIOG->BSRR = 0b0010000000000000 <<16;
    }
}
```

I am doing this on Discovery Board STM32-F429ZIT

Comment: Can you explain what each line of code does? I don't want to go look up the registers for your processor.

Comment: Even for this a circuit diagram can be of great help. Where is the LED from-too. Series resistopr? Value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see dimming only is because you do not have a delay in your code. You need to toggle LED, and then wait set period (repeat forever). Note the Microcontroller is running at 180MHz, meaning you actually can't see with your eye that the power is turning off.

Comment: Oh man, such a rookie mistake... Thank you very much